# Loose threader in LTO-5 SAS internal drive

Tags: tape, tapedrive, lto

Once more I have a tape drive issue.

I started seeing lots and lots of hardware errors with our LTO-5 SAS drive within our Superloader 3 changer. The main upshot was that the drive would think a tape was loaded when it was not.  I can add specific error messages here later on.

To buy support for this hardware will be more expensive than buying a new drive, so before buying fresh new hardware, I figured I'd try to (carefully) fix this one, only performing tricky actions when I can find information that supports it. I opened up the drive.

I saw the following:

[image: Tape drive, loose threader]

From reading, I've learned that the part that I'm pointing to is the threader, which is supposed to link up with the leader pin on the LTO cartridges, to take up the actual tape in the cartridge.

From my other changer, I've seen that when there is no tape loaded, the threader is supposed to go through the black plastic assembly at the top right, then down along the right edge, into a section below the greenish tab with '3003' printed on it.

I'll probably just buy a new tape drive but in the meantime, I was wondering if someone would know how I might get the threader through the way it originally was before the issue.